# How must a development environment be set up to build prestashop theme assets?

Tags: windows-10, prestashop, development-environment, prestashop-1.7

I'm trying to build the Prestashop `classic` theme's assets, according to [Prestashop's documentation](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/development/compile-assets/).  I'm on Windows 10, using cygwin. Here is what I did in detail:

- I forked the latest stable tag (`1.7.6.7`).
- I ran `./tools/assets/build.sh` in `cygwin`. (I also tried in Windows Terminal and [step by step](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/development/compile-assets/#compiling-assets), i.e. cd theme dir, followed by `npm install`.)

`npm install` threw an error complaining about missing `Python`.

```
gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
```

- I installed Python 3 and got an error complaining about missing `Python 2.7`
- I installed Python 2.7 and got an error complaining about missing `Visual Studio 2008`.

  ```
    Projet "E:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\themes\classic\_dev\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln" sur le noud 1 (cibles par défaut).
    ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
      Génération de la configuration de solution "Release|x64".
    MSBUILD : error MSB3411: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". If the component is not installed, either 1) install the Microsoft 
    Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5, or 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2008.  
    [E:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\themes\classic\_dev\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln]
    Génération du projet "E:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\themes\classic\_dev\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln"
    terminée (cibles par défaut) -- ÉCHEC.
  ```

Before I continue on a trial and error basis, I'd like to ask if someone knows what prerequisites are needed to set up a complete development environment for Prestashop themes. Or more precisely, what is the list of software I must install before being able to run `npm install`?

https://devdocs.prestashop.com/ clearly doesn't give any clue, they only explain installation of `npm` and `composer` [here](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/basics/installation/localhost/).

How to set up a Prestashop development environment?

Answer (score 1):

The answer was not straight forward:

The theme uses `node-sass`, which is compiled using `node-gyp`.

As the [readme of node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows) states, on Windows we need to install `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`, which takes care of Python and Visual Studio.

The theme of the latest stable release of Prestashop 1.7.6.7 uses a `node-sass` version (`^4.11.0`), [which is not compatible](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2794) with node 12.x

Therefore, we need to install [nvm for windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) and use the latest version of the node 10.x branch.

With these steps, `npm install` will work.

`npm run build` will fail, because the npm script is not compatible with Windows.
In stead of `npm run build` (which calls `NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --colors --debug --display-chunks`), we have to run

```
set NODE_ENV=production
npx webpack --progress --colors --debug --display-chunks
```

It looks like the Devs of Prestashop never tried to get their work running on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Classic theme uses webpack to compile assets, more informations:
https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/development/compile-assets/

Best way is to navigate to `themes/classic/_dev` and run `npm install` :) later you can use `npm run watch` or `npm run build` or any other defined script

Comment: Thanks. Maybe, I was not clear enough. I included this link already in my question, and sure, I tried to `npm install`, but this is exactly what doesn't work. `webpack` would be installed by npm, if it worked.